# Is there a way to set img src if onload has not fired within N seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following javascript to generate dynamic html.

```
var imgHtml =
    "<img src='" + imgSrc + "'
     onload='fadeImg(this)'
     onerror='this.onerror = null; this.src='default.png' />"


function fadeImg(obj) {
    $(obj).fadeTo( 1000, $(obj).attr(.7) );
}
```

Sometimes `imgSrc` is a url to a very large animated gif.  If `imgSrc` takes longer than 5 seconds to load, then I would like to just stop the file transfer and display `default.png` instead.

How would I be able to do this?  Is there a way I can give `onload` 5000ms to be called and if it doesn't then default to `default.png`?

**EDIT**

```
var imgHtml =
    "<img src='" + imgSrc + "'
     data-opacity='{data-opacity}'
     class='thumbnail' 
     onload='fadeImg(this)'
     onerror='this.onerror = null; this.src='default.png' />"


function fadeImg(obj) {
    $(obj).fadeTo( 1000, $(obj).attr('data-opacity')/100 );
}
```

Comment: Why are you using javascript to push javascript into HTML? Just use javascript to build your element and add event handlers.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use a timer:

```
function loadImageShort(url, altUrl, timeout) {
    var img = new Image(), timer;

    img.onload = function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    };

    img.onerror = function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        img.onerror = null;
        img.src = altUrl;
    };

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        if (!img.complete) {
            img.src = altUrl;
        }
    }, timeout);

    img.src = url;
    return img;
}


var img = loadImageShort("http://example.com/mainimg.jpg", "http://example.com/backupimg.jpg", 5000);

// now set other properties
img.className = "thumbnail";
img.setAttribute("data-opacity", "{data-opacity}");
```

Comment: I love it when the plain JS solution is easier to read than jQuery.

Comment: @AustinMullins - yeah, my pet peeve is this: `$(this).attr("src", url);` when you could just do `this.src = url;`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Once I have the image object, how do I template it as html into the variable `imgHtml`?  I just edited my original question to include the custom attributes and class name I want as part of the img element

Comment: @user784637 - You can just set other properties on the image object.  I've shown some in my answer.  You can either do those after the function or you can integrate them into the function if you're doing it the same every time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setTimeout()` and clear it if image does load.

```
var timer = setTimeout(function(){
   $('$imageId').attr('src', '/path/to/default');
},5000);

function fadeImg(obj) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(obj).fadeTo( 1000, $(obj).attr(.7) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a timeout to set flags, which check, if the picture was already loaded, and if not, set a new one:

```js
var img = document.getElementById('image'),
  isAborted = false,
  isLoaded = false,
  waitForAbort = 5000; // milliseconds

// fire this, when the image finished loading
var onloadHandler = function () {
  if (!isAborted) {
    isLoaded = true;
    console.log('I finshed loading');
  }
};

// set the onload handler and start loading the image
img.onload = onloadHandler;
img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/oWkTtiQ.gif';

// set a timeout, to change the picture to a placeholder
setTimeout(function () {
  if (!isLoaded) {
    isAborted = true;
    img.src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100.png'; // placeholder
  }
}, waitForAbort);
```

```html
<img id="image">
```